# how to use ad mob with google web designer?

Tags: admob, interstitial

I have recently started using [google web designer](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/?hl=en#topic=3249465) to try and create some interstitials. When I publish my ad in "admob format", I get some zip file on my local host. What do I do with it in order to "insert it" into Ad mob as a new ad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an account setup with a service that delivers ads, like AdMob.  The AdMob platform includes objects called Campaigns.  You create a Campaign object to deliver the ad you create, and publish locally in Web Designer.

After you have published your new HTML5 ad locally, you can then upload it to AdMob as part of a Campaign.